# Instagram. Как с помощью JS заполнить input-ы "логин", "пароль" и залогиниться?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javafx

Проблема в следующем: на странице https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ нужно средствами JS заполнить данные формы и нажать на кнопку **"Войти"**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При установке атрибута **"value"** инпуты вроде бы заполняются, но при нажатии на **"Войти"** поля сбрасываются на пустые значения. То же наблюдается, если заполнить одно из полей и начать набирать текст в другом. Буду благодарен за любую помощь по теме.

Чистый **JS** или **JQuery** - значения не имеет, только бы значения не сбрасывались.

P.S.: не срабатывает ни один из известных мне способов установки атрибута value:

- `document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].setAttribute('value', 'bla-bla-bla')`
- `document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = 'bla-bla-bla'`
- `$('input[name="username"]').val('bla-bla-bla')`
- `$('input[name="username"]').attr('value', 'bla-bla-bla')`
- `$('input[name="username"]').prop('value', 'bla-bla-bla')`

Есть подозрения что должен быть инициализирован какой-то **event**, но какой - расковырять не удалось.

Comment: Пробуй копипастить через JS туда, мб там присвоение значений на инпуте/кейдауне ведется, пробуй фокусить перед этим В общем повторяй все те же манипуляции, которые проделал бы обычный пользователь.

Comment: Средствами js - это через браузерное расширение то есть?

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка Очевидно, что да.

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка как вам угодно, мне это в WebView в javaFX нужно выполнить и я просто в ступоре, ибо заполнение полей не срабатывает. Но что-то же должно работать, так как в том же Chrome родное автозаполнение формы отрабатывается же.

Comment: Для ВКашного окошко такое прокатывало. А то, что поля сбрасываются на пустые - может быть логин/пароль не правильные? Или он просто сбрасывает и все?

Answer (score 1):

Если это и возможно, не думаю что это хорошая практика, если это будет использоваться для широкого использования, это означает что пользователи должны вводить свои конфиденциальные данные (логин и пароль) где то на вашем сервисе а не на странице инстаграмма.

P.s. на питоне через расширение splinter проблем с такой задачей не было, получал элемент страницы по name и заполнял.

Comment: К счастью (или сожалению, уж не знаю) для широкого использования сия поделка не предназначается. Просто небольшая программка для частного пользования. Пока обхожу вход окольными путями: логин через фейсбук, но что-то мне подсказывает, что это как-то через ж***. API инстаграма использовать не вариант ибо для моих целей это как из пушки по воробьям, да и полноценный доступ к API не получить без готового к релизу приложения. А так как ни о каких релизах речи не идет... В общем, всем спасибо за внимание, все что я понял, так это если кто-то и знает как обойти, то не расколется)

Comment: Да почему ж не расколется. Я ж говорю я на питоне модулем splinter обошел. А кстати у них точно нельзя это делать просто из кода, то есть не получится послать request просто. Вам в любом случае нужно нечто эмулирующее браузер. Посмотрите в сторону phantomJS он вроде как именно для этого.